# How To Disable Button in Lightning Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I Have a page which contains 10 buttons. Here I want to highlight some buttons, but all buttons should visible on the page.

Note: By Using Disable Function We achieve it when I use disable function getting an error like pass a value to it.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using which giving you the error?

Comment: You need to pass true or false value to the disable attribute. Set it to true to disable the button and false to let users click it.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty i have used true its working.thanks